# jQuery won't let me do if blocks?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to do a fade effect, that fades out a div and substitutes it for another. For that I have created a lastDiv var which sets the number of the last div clicked.

But when I try to set an if js says there is an error. I am pretty sure that I am using the correct syntax. (I am a beginner)

Thanks

```
var lastDiv = 1;

$("#item1").click(function () {
    if(lastDiv == 2) {  $("#div2").fadeOut(0500, function() { $("#div1").fadeIn(500, function () {lastDiv = 1;});   });  }); }
    else if (lastDiv == 3) {  $("#div3").fadeOut(0500, function() { $("#div1").fadeIn(500, function () {lastDiv = 1;}); });  }); }


$("#item2").click(function () {
    if(lastDiv == 1){   $("#div1").fadeOut(0500, function() { $("#div2").fadeIn(0500, function () {lastDiv = 2;}) });  }); }
    else if(lastDiv == 3){  $("#div3").fadeOut(0500, function() { $("#div2").fadeIn(0500, function () {lastDiv = 2;}) });  }); }


$("#item3").click(function () {
    if(lastDiv == 1) { $("#div1").fadeOut(0500, function() { $("#div3").fadeIn(0500, function () { lastDiv = 3 })  }); }
    else if(lastDiv == 2) { $("#div2").fadeOut(0500, function() { $("#div3").fadeIn(0500, function () { lastDiv = 3 })  }); } }); 

</script>
```

Comment: This is a pretty bad habit. Why not putting all those blocks on new lines?

Comment: Properly indenting these quickly reveals the errors in bracing.

Comment: Everything is so much easier with proper indentation. I indented the first handler for you, I'm sure you can figure out the problem. Also if you had a look at the console, you'd have seen *"SyntaxError: Unexpected token )"*. Such questions don't belong here IMO (too localized), you should be able to fix such errors on your own.

Comment: @FelixKling That is the whole error that the OP was trying to solve!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your braces are all messed up:
I put your code through a [beautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/):

```
var lastDiv = 1;

$("#item1").click(function () {
    if (lastDiv == 2) {
        $("#div2").fadeOut(0500, function () {
            $("#div1").fadeIn(500, function () {
                lastDiv = 1;
            });
        });
    });
} else if (lastDiv == 3) {
    $("#div3").fadeOut(0500, function () {
        $("#div1").fadeIn(500, function () {
            lastDiv = 1;
        });
    });
});
}


$("#item2").click(function () {
    if (lastDiv == 1) {
        $("#div1").fadeOut(0500, function () {
            $("#div2").fadeIn(0500, function () {
                lastDiv = 2;
            })
        });
    });
} else if (lastDiv == 3) {
    $("#div3").fadeOut(0500, function () {
        $("#div2").fadeIn(0500, function () {
            lastDiv = 2;
        })
    });
});
}


$("#item3").click(function () {
    if (lastDiv == 1) {
        $("#div1").fadeOut(0500, function () {
            $("#div3").fadeIn(0500, function () {
                lastDiv = 3
            })
        });
    } else if (lastDiv == 2) {
        $("#div2").fadeOut(0500, function () {
            $("#div3").fadeIn(0500, function () {
                lastDiv = 3
            })
        });
    }
});
```

You should have an **error** in the browser!

Answer (score 1):

This is what your code looks like, with proper indenting and new lines:

```
$("#item1").click(function () {
    if(lastDiv == 2) {
        $("#div2").fadeOut(0500, function() {
            $("#div1").fadeIn(500, function () {
                lastDiv = 1;
            });
        });
    });
} else if (lastDiv == 3) {
    $("#div3").fadeOut(0500, function() {
        $("#div1").fadeIn(500, function () {
            lastDiv = 1;
        });
    });
});
}
```

See the problem? The `else if` part goes after the closing tag of `function() {`, and not `if`. That's a syntax error, that javascript did not tell you about. Try installing FireBug, an addon for Firefox or similar so that you can see such errors.

And please, don't write this code on one single line. I don't know how you can read it.

Answer (score 1):

There were quite a few syntax errors with your `if` statements, closing of brackets, and the odd semi-colon. I've fixed them for you and indented everything to make it easier to read. I've also removed the leading zero. I've only done your first `click` event, but hopefully it should help a bit! :)

```
$("#item1").click(function ()
{
    if (lastDiv == 2)
    {
        $("#div2").fadeOut(500, function()
        {
            $("#div1").fadeIn(500, function()
            {
                lastDiv = 1;
            });
        }); 
    }
    else if (lastDiv == 3)
    {
        $("#div3").fadeOut(500, function()
        {
            $("#div1").fadeIn(500, function()
            {
                lastDiv = 1;
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have a misplaced }); in there, amongst a couple other syntax problems.  Spacing out your code and indenting will help you see those types of problems better:

```
var lastDiv = 1;

$("#item1").click(function (){
    if(lastDiv == 2){
        $("#div2").fadeOut(0500, function(){
            $("#div1").fadeIn(500, function(){
                lastDiv = 1;
            });
        });
    }else if(lastDiv == 3){
        $("#div3").fadeOut(0500, function(){
            $("#div1").fadeIn(500, function(){
                lastDiv = 1;
            });
        });
    }
});

$("#item2").click(function (){
    if(lastDiv == 1){
        $("#div1").fadeOut(0500, function(){
            $("#div2").fadeIn(500, function(){
                lastDiv = 2;
            });
        });
    }else if(lastDiv == 3){
        $("#div3").fadeOut(0500, function(){
            $("#div2").fadeIn(500, function(){
                lastDiv = 2;
            });
        });
    }
});

$("#item3").click(function (){
    if(lastDiv == 1){
        $("#div1").fadeOut(0500, function(){
            $("#div3").fadeIn(500, function(){
                lastDiv = 3;
            });
        });
    }else if(lastDiv == 2){
        $("#div2").fadeOut(0500, function(){
            $("#div3").fadeIn(500, function(){
                lastDiv = 3;
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume the the divs have `class="content"` and clickable elements have `class="item"` and the attribute `data-i = n`, where `n` is 1, 2, 3.

You can simplify the code considerably by fading out all content divs unconditionally, though presumably only one will actually be faded out (others will remain hidden), then finding the correct content div to fade in.

```
$(".item").click(function () {
    var index = $(this).data('i');//or similar - there are other possibilities here.
    $(".content").fadeOut(500, function() {
        $("#div"+index).fadeIn(500);//fade in the content div corresponding to the clicked item
    });
});
```

This not only fixes your bug but also better exploits the power of jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are trying to do:

```
var selected = null;
var selectors = ["#div1","#div2","#div3"]; // use any valid jquery selectors

var selectme = function(){  
    if (selected==this)
        return;

    selected = this;

    $.each(selectors,function(key,selector){
        $(selector).fadeTo(300,0.2);
    });

    $(selected).fadeTo(300,1);
};

$(document).ready(function(){
    $.each(selectors,function(key,selector){
        $(selector).click(selectme);
    });

    $(selectors[0]).click();
});
```